# NodeJs blockchain on private ethereum

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

I have created simple blockchain application using NodeJS. The blockchain data file is getting stored on local File System. There is no mining blocks, no difficulty level involved in this blockchain.

Please suggest, if I can host this application on private ethereum / hyperledge, and what all changes I would need to do for this? Below code I'm using for creating blocks.

### Sample Genesis Block

```
[{"index":0,"previousHash":"0","timestamp":1465154705,"transaction":{"id":"0","transactionHash":"0","type":"","data":{"StudInfo":[{"id":"","studentId":"","parenterId":"","schemeId":"","batchId":"","instructorId":"","trainingId":"","skillId":""}]},"fromAddress":""},"hash":"816534932c2b7154836da6afc367695e6337db8a921823784c14378abed4f7d7"}]
```

### Sample Code(NodeJS)

```
var generateNextBlock = (blockData) => {
    var previousBlock = getLatestBlock();
    var nextIndex = previousBlock.index + 1;
    var nextTimestamp = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
    var nextHash = calculateHash(nextIndex, previousBlock.hash, nextTimestamp, blockData);

    return new Block(nextIndex, previousBlock.hash, nextTimestamp, blockData, nextHash);
};

var calculateHashForBlock = (block) => {
    return calculateHash(block.index, block.previousHash, block.timestamp, block.transaction);
};

var calculateHash = (index, previousHash, timestamp, transaction) => {
    return CryptoJS.SHA256(index + previousHash + timestamp + transaction).toString();
};

var addBlock = (newBlock) => {
    if (isValidNewBlock(newBlock, getLatestBlock())) {
        blockchain.push(newBlock);
        blocksDb.write(blockchain);
    }
};

var isValidNewBlock = (newBlock, previousBlock) => {
    if (previousBlock.index + 1 !== newBlock.index) {
        console.log('invalid index');
        return false;
    } else if (previousBlock.hash !== newBlock.previousHash) {
        console.log('invalid previoushash');
        return false;
    } else if (calculateHashForBlock(newBlock) !== newBlock.hash) {
        console.log(typeof (newBlock.hash) + ' ' + typeof calculateHashForBlock(newBlock));
        console.log('invalid hash: ' + calculateHashForBlock(newBlock) + ' ' + newBlock.hash);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
};
```

Comment: My team is working on providing secure private storage over an Ethereum-compatible blockchain. There is a [NodeJS SDK](https://github.com/lightstreams-network/js-sdk-lightstreams) to connect through our gateway (or using your own local gateway). By using this you may implement a distributed storage in very few steps. If you are looking for a framework to test your DApp, we also implemented an [ethereum compatible blockchain](https://github.com/lightstreams-network/lightchain) with much better performance on the transaction time and a significant reduction in the cost per transaction.

Answer (score 4):

Congratulations if you have gotten this far you have successfully setup Geth on AWS. Now we will go over how to configure an Ethereum node. Make sure you are in your home directory on your cloud server with the pwd command and then create a new folder called whatever you want to create the genesis block of your Ethereum blockchain. You can do this with the following commands. The first command is to create the folder, change directory into the folder and then create a file called genesis.json.

mkdir mlg-ethchain cd mlg-ethchain nano genesis.json

To create a private blockchain you need to define the genesis block. Genesis blocks are usually embedded in the client but with Ethereum you are able to configure a genesis block using a json object. Paste the following JSON object into your genesis.json file and we explain each variable in the following section.

```html
{
"nonce": "0xdeadbeefdeadbeef",
"timestamp": "0x0",
"parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"extraData": "0x0",
"gasLimit": "0x8000000",
"difficulty": "0x400",
"Mixhash": 
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", "coinbase": "0x3333333333333333333333333333333333333333",
"alloc": {
}
}
```

The coinbase is the default address of the mining address. Because you have not created a wallet yet this can be set to whatever you want provided that it is a valid Ethereum address. Difficulty is how hard it is for a miner to create a new block. For testing and development purposes it is recommended that you start with a low difficulty and then increase it. The parentHash is the hash of the parent block which doesnt exist because this is the first block in the chain. The gasLimit is the maximum amount of gas that is required to execute a transaction or send tokens from one account to another. The nonce is a random number for this block. This is the number that every miner has to guess to define the block but for the first block it must be hardcoded. You are able to provide any extraData is the extraData section. In the alloc section you can allocate a number of premined tokens or ether to certain addresses at the beginning of the blockchain. We do not want to do this so we will keep it blank.

After you have confirmed this you can check the file to make sure it has been configured correctly with the cat command. From the same directory input this command.

cat genesis.json

Comment: thanks for response. Please suggest if I can have custom geneses block defined as below, [{"index":0,"previousHash":"0","timestamp":1465154705,"transaction":{"id":"0","transactionHash":"0","type":"","data":{"StudInfo":[{"id":"","studentId":"","parenterId":"","schemeId":"","batchId":"","instructorId":"","trainingId":"","skillId":""}]},"fromAddress":""},"hash":"816534932c2b7154836da6afc367695e6337db8a921823784c14378abed4f7d7"}].

Comment: added sample source code and genesis block I'm using to create custom blockchain.

Comment: Not that it really matters, but I don't think the OP mentioned they're on AWS anywhere. That first sentence sounds pretty much like unsolicited advertising.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, your JS code does some sort of low-level block generation (albeit in a centralised/standalone way). I'm not sure of the purpose of that code, but it's not an app that you could "port to" Ethereum or Hyperledger [Fabric], since the role of those blockchain engines is precisely to implement the block generation logic for you.

A JS app designed to work with Ethereum wouldn't do any of the block management. At the contrary, it would perform high-level and client-level interaction with a smart contract, which is basically a class (similar to Java classes) available on the whole network and whose methods are guaranteed by the network to do what they're meant to. Your JS app would essentially call the smart contract's methods as a client without caring about any block production issues.

In other, more vague but maybe more familiar terms:

- Client: the JS app
- Server/backend: the smart contract
- Infrastructure/engine: Ethereum

On Ethereum, the way you get to the smart contract as a client is by sending RPC calls in JSON (hence the name JSON-RPC) to the contract's methods. The communication is done by embedding that JSON over HTTP to an Ethereum node, preferably your own. In Javascript, a few libraries such as web3 give you a higher-level abstraction view so that you don't need to care about JSON-RPC and you can think of your contract's methods as normal Javascript functions.

Also, since you're asking about private Ethereum: another consequence of that distribution of layers is that client code and smart contracts don't need to care about whether the Ethereum network is a public or a private one, i.e. what consensus protocol is in place. To make a bold analogy, it's similar to how SQL queries or schemas stay the same no matter how the database is persisted on disk.

Interaction with Hyperledger Fabric is similar in concept, except that you do plain REST calls to an HTTP endpoint exposed by the network. I'm not sure what client-level abstraction libraries are available.